Algorithm to calculate visual similarity of two point trajectories
I have a program where I let a user draw an image and record the strokes by saving the coordinates. I save the coordinates on every "onMove" event so it is highly detailed, with one point every couple pixels. Then I reduce the complexity with Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm, rescale it, turn it by 180 degrees and let it draw by a robot.
The robots result then again gets stored. I do have the robots results as an image (png), but I could also save the coordinates if that would make things easier.
Now I want to calculate the accuracy of the robots drawing compared to the input (rescaled, turned coordinates with reduces complexity).
I cannot use simple Sum of Squared Error, because the density of coordinates highly varies between the fresh drawing and the reduced input. I also assume that I cannot just reduce the robots strokes as well, since slight differences in the curve may lead to heavily different results in the reduction algorithm and it cannot be guaranteed that they result in the same amount of clouds at all.
Best would be if I could compare the fit of the strokes onto the lines produced by the previous reduced input. (Similarly to comparing a visual curve to a Bezier-curve.) However, the amount of "turns" within one stroke is variable especially since the accuracy of the robot can vary.
The point sets represent an image where each point is connected to the previous one by a straight line like this:

There can be multiple points on one line, especially in the unreduced form of the robots dataset.
It would be best to have an algorithm that calculates each points distance from the lines, similar to the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm only that the points in question are not part of the set and the calculation in question is not the distance from one specific line but from the closest line of the set.
Which algorithm can I use for that?
Here's an example image of input and output:


Seems to me you’re just trying to measure the distance (i.e. deviation) between two curves. And the curves happen to be polylines.
So suppose one polyline $\mathbf P$ has points $P_1, \ldots, P_m$ and the other one $\mathbf Q$ has points $Q_1, \ldots, Q_n$.
Write yourself a function that calculates the distance from a point $X$ to a line segment. Use this to write a higher-level function that calculates the distance from $X$ to a polyline (just the min of distances to the polyline’s segments).
For $i=1,2, \ldots, m$ calculate the distance from $P_i$ to $\mathbf Q$. Let $u$ be the maximum of these distances.
For $j=1,2, \ldots, n$ calculate the distance from $Q_j$ to $\mathbf P$. Let $v$ be the maximum of these distances.
Then use the maximum of $u$ and $v$ as your measure of the distance between the two polylines.
All of this is somewhat related to the concept of so-called Hausdorff distance between curves. You can Google that term to learn more.
There is code here, but I don’t know how good it is. And one relevant paper here.

Why do we take the maximum of the distances and not the sum of all distances divided by the amount of points? Wouldn't this measure the maximum diversion existing instead of an average of the diversion over the whole picture?
Why do I calculate the distance from the points of the "correct" solution to the other one as well? Is it because the amount of points differs between the two sets?

You can decide what measure of “distance” you want to use. The alternatives you suggested are reasonable.

Suppose you had two polylines that each had 20 points. And suppose these points were the same, except that the 9th points differ by a distance d. What is the the distance between these two polylines? In my opinion, the distance is d. If you think d/20 is a better distance measure, then feel free to use it.
